# expo eas -p ios fails during fastlane

Tags: react-native, expo, cocoapods, eas

When building with the command *eas build -p ios*, I get an error from my fastlane. I provided some of the fastlane information below. I highlighted the errors. The error I have at the very bottom I have seen before, but normally I fix it by using xcode to clean the build. I am unsure how to solve or even debug these errors without xcode.

EDIT: I did update my xcode command line tools. I also tried *eas build -p ios --clear-cache*. I am not sure how to go about debugging this.

EDIT 2: I was able to get the app to build, but it crashes amongst launch so I am assuming these errors still need to be fixed

If there is any other information I can provide, please let me know.

Here are the Xcode logs from the eas build: https://easyupload.io/m7bj1a

```
Resolving Swift Package Manager dependencies...
$ xcodebuild -resolvePackageDependencies -workspace ./appname.xcworkspace -scheme appname -configuration Release
▸ 2023-01-19 23:43:13.333 xcodebuild[4123:11533] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
▸ 2023-01-19 23:43:13.334 xcodebuild[4123:11533] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
▸ 2023-01-19 23:43:13.391 xcodebuild[4123:11533] XType: failed to connect - Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.fonts was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.fonts was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process.}
▸ 2023-01-19 23:43:13.391 xcodebuild[4123:11533] Font server protocol version mismatch (expected:5 got:0), falling back to local fonts
▸ 2023-01-19 23:43:13.391 xcodebuild[4123:11533] XType: unable to make a connection to the font daemon!
▸ 2023-01-19 23:43:13.391 xcodebuild[4123:11533] XType: XTFontStaticRegistry is enabled as fontd is not available.
▸ Command line invocation:
▸     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -resolvePackageDependencies -workspace ./appname.xcworkspace -scheme appname -configuration Release
▸ User defaults from command line:
▸     IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES
▸ --- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
▸ { platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Any iOS Device }
▸ { platform:iOS Simulator, id:dvtdevice-DVTiOSDeviceSimulatorPlaceholder-iphonesimulator:placeholder, name:Any iOS Simulator Device }
▸ { platform:iOS Simulator, id:F6898BCF-1F9B-4017-8C00-C42FB52DC78B, OS:15.5, name:iPad (9th generation) }
▸ { platform:iOS Simulator, id:8A99E458-9DF5-45FD-90B9-AE3E8D45FA33, OS:15.5, name:iPad Air (5th generation) }
▸ { platform:iOS Simulator, id:A9D00E67-59F6-498B-9487-E6CB0CFACD0C, OS:15.5, name:iPad Pro (9.7-inch) }
▸ { platform:iOS Simulator, id:DB619EE2-A7AB-4B01-8E7F-C3FD0489483E, OS:15.5, name:iPad Pro (11-inch) (3rd generation) }
▸ { platform:iOS Simulator, id:F86ECD5C-8048-4456-A2EE-A5092F5099F4, OS:15.5, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (5th generation) }
▸ { platform:iOS Simulator, id:D38333AD-1820-41A9-9179-7BA12C6A00F9, OS:15.5, name:iPad mini (6th generation) }
▸ { platform:iOS Simulator, id:B575F055-31BB-4681-A541-93C73D3E05F7, OS:15.5, name:iPhone 8 }
▸ { platform:iOS Simulator, id:E65EE165-322D-430E-8955-428C34DC9E07, OS:15.5, name:iPhone 8 Plus }
▸ { platform:iOS Simulator, id:EAFFB577-ED7C-4B60-A91D-20CF70EBFBA0, OS:15.5, name:iPhone 11 }
▸ { platform:iOS Simulator, id:F6667EA1-F6F7-4304-B9D2-495992F0BC20, OS:15.5, name:iPhone 11 Pro }
▸ { platform:iOS Simulator, id:F0CA4CF6-38BA-4D2E-AFBC-22EE1526754A, OS:15.5, name:iPhone 11 Pro Max }
▸ { platform:iOS Simulator, id:4A1C0E71-0C96-40AD-A725-C6A370AF1D93, OS:15.5, name:iPhone 12 }
▸ { platform:iOS Simulator, id:A5DACA53-368C-4AA9-B649-B1D379696C68, OS:15.5, name:iPhone 12 Pro }
▸ { platform:iOS Simulator, id:1C40B471-BD95-4AD2-8E02-A4487E25EF3B, OS:15.5, name:iPhone 12 Pro Max }
▸ { platform:iOS Simulator, id:4814B63C-8DE9-44CC-A80D-8D60D42C655A, OS:15.5, name:iPhone 12 mini }
▸ { platform:iOS Simulator, id:8E2EB5DD-C321-4695-B728-F6A27FAF7D67, OS:15.5, name:iPhone 13 }
▸ { platform:iOS Simulator, id:4E56612B-11ED-49F2-B5EF-6E4602B0FB79, OS:15.5, name:iPhone 13 Pro }
▸ { platform:iOS Simulator, id:E5FAE80A-C4BD-4BFE-A831-2F7049886894, OS:15.5, name:iPhone 13 Pro Max }
▸ { platform:iOS Simulator, id:E4D323B3-630D-4D28-A329-6870D721E3B2, OS:15.5, name:iPhone 13 mini }
▸ { platform:iOS Simulator, id:DB03CB85-009E-4017-8EBE-14EC01AE8FD2, OS:15.5, name:iPhone SE (3rd generation) }
▸ { platform:iOS Simulator, id:A147CC3C-E896-4D76-9012-878356117872, OS:15.5, name:iPod touch (7th generation) }
▸ resolved source packages:
$ xcodebuild -showBuildSettings -workspace ./appname.xcworkspace -scheme appname -configuration Release
❌ [stderr] 2023-01-19 23:43:17.278 xcodebuild[4132:11650] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
❌ [stderr] 2023-01-19 23:43:17.278 xcodebuild[4132:11650] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
❌ [stderr] 2023-01-19 23:43:17.335 xcodebuild[4132:11650] XType: failed to connect - Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.fonts was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.fonts was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process.}
❌ [stderr] 2023-01-19 23:43:17.335 xcodebuild[4132:11650] Font server protocol version mismatch (expected:5 got:0), falling back to local fonts
❌ [stderr] 2023-01-19 23:43:17.335 xcodebuild[4132:11650] XType: unable to make a connection to the font daemon!
❌ [stderr] 2023-01-19 23:43:17.335 xcodebuild[4132:11650] XType: XTFontStaticRegistry is enabled as fontd is not available.
❌ [stderr] --- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
❌ [stderr] { platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Any iOS Device }
❌ [stderr] { platform:iOS Simulator, id:dvtdevice-DVTiOSDeviceSimulatorPlaceholder-iphonesimulator:placeholder, name:Any iOS Simulator Device }
❌ [stderr] { platform:iOS Simulator, id:F6898BCF-1F9B-4017-8C00-C42FB52DC78B, OS:15.5,  name:iPad (9th generation) }
❌ [stderr] { platform:iOS Simulator, id:8A99E458-9DF5-45FD-90B9-AE3E8D45FA33, OS:15.5, name:iPad Air (5th generation) }
❌ [stderr] { platform:iOS Simulator, id:A9D00E67-59F6-498B-9487-E6CB0CFACD0C, OS:15.5, name:iPad Pro (9.7-inch) }
❌ [stderr] { platform:iOS Simulator, id:DB619EE2-A7AB-4B01-8E7F-C3FD0489483E, OS:15.5, name:iPad Pro (11-inch) (3rd generation) }
❌ [stderr] { platform:iOS Simulator, id:F86ECD5C-8048-4456-A2EE-A5092F5099F4, OS:15.5, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (5th generation) }
❌ [stderr] { platform:iOS Simulator, id:D38333AD-1820-41A9-9179-7BA12C6A00F9, OS:15.5, name:iPad mini (6th generation) }
❌ [stderr] { platform:iOS Simulator, id:B575F055-31BB-4681-A541-93C73D3E05F7, OS:15.5, name:iPhone 8 }
❌ [stderr] { platform:iOS Simulator, id:E65EE165-322D-430E-8955-428C34DC9E07, OS:15.5, name:iPhone 8 Plus }
❌ [stderr] { platform:iOS Simulator, id:EAFFB577-ED7C-4B60-A91D-20CF70EBFBA0, OS:15.5, name:iPhone 11 }
❌ [stderr] { platform:iOS Simulator, id:F6667EA1-F6F7-4304-B9D2-495992F0BC20, OS:15.5, name:iPhone 11 Pro }
❌ [stderr] { platform:iOS Simulator, id:F0CA4CF6-38BA-4D2E-AFBC-22EE1526754A, OS:15.5, name:iPhone 11 Pro Max }
❌ [stderr] { platform:iOS Simulator, id:4A1C0E71-0C96-40AD-A725-C6A370AF1D93, OS:15.5, name:iPhone 12 }
❌ [stderr] { platform:iOS Simulator, id:A5DACA53-368C-4AA9-B649-B1D379696C68, OS:15.5, name:iPhone 12 Pro }
❌ [stderr] { platform:iOS Simulator, id:1C40B471-BD95-4AD2-8E02-A4487E25EF3B, OS:15.5, name:iPhone 12 Pro Max }
❌ [stderr] { platform:iOS Simulator, id:4814B63C-8DE9-44CC-A80D-8D60D42C655A, OS:15.5, name:iPhone 12 mini }
❌ [stderr] { platform:iOS Simulator, id:8E2EB5DD-C321-4695-B728-F6A27FAF7D67, OS:15.5, name:iPhone 13 }
❌ [stderr] { platform:iOS Simulator, id:4E56612B-11ED-49F2-B5EF-6E4602B0FB79, OS:15.5, name:iPhone 13 Pro }
❌ [stderr] { platform:iOS Simulator, id:E5FAE80A-C4BD-4BFE-A831-2F7049886894, OS:15.5, name:iPhone 13 Pro Max }
❌ [stderr] { platform:iOS Simulator, id:E4D323B3-630D-4D28-A329-6870D721E3B2, OS:15.5, name:iPhone 13 mini }
❌ [stderr] { platform:iOS Simulator, id:DB03CB85-009E-4017-8EBE-14EC01AE8FD2, OS:15.5, name:iPhone SE (3rd generation) }
❌ [stderr] { platform:iOS Simulator, id:A147CC3C-E896-4D76-9012-878356117872, OS:15.5, name:iPod touch (7th generation) }
Command timed out after 3 seconds on try 1 of 4, trying again with a 6 second timeout...
❌ [stderr] 2023-01-19 23:43:20.292 xcodebuild[4145:11723] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
❌ [stderr] 2023-01-19 23:43:20.292 xcodebuild[4145:11723] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
❌ [stderr] 2023-01-19 23:43:20.344 xcodebuild[4145:11723] XType: failed to connect - Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.fonts was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.fonts was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process.}
❌ [stderr] 2023-01-19 23:43:20.344 xcodebuild[4145:11723] Font server protocol version mismatch (expected:5 got:0), falling back to local fonts
❌ [stderr] 2023-01-19 23:43:20.344 xcodebuild[4145:11723] XType: unable to make a connection to the font daemon!
❌ [stderr] 2023-01-19 23:43:20.344 xcodebuild[4145:11723] XType: XTFontStaticRegistry is enabled as fontd is not available.
❌ [stderr] --- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
❌ [stderr] { platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Any iOS Device }
❌ [stderr] { platform:iOS Simulator, id:dvtdevice-DVTiOSDeviceSimulatorPlaceholder-iphonesimulator:placeholder, name:Any iOS Simulator Device }
❌ [stderr] { platform:iOS Simulator, id:F6898BCF-1F9B-4017-8C00-C42FB52DC78B, OS:15.5, name:iPad (9th generation) }
❌ [stderr] { platform:iOS Simulator, id:8A99E458-9DF5-45FD-90B9-AE3E8D45FA33, OS:15.5, name:iPad Air (5th generation) }
❌ [stderr] { platform:iOS Simulator, id:A9D00E67-59F6-498B-9487-E6CB0CFACD0C, OS:15.5, name:iPad Pro (9.7-inch) }
❌ [stderr] { platform:iOS Simulator, id:DB619EE2-A7AB-4B01-8E7F-C3FD0489483E, OS:15.5, name:iPad Pro (11-inch) (3rd generation) }
❌ [stderr] { platform:iOS Simulator, id:F86ECD5C-8048-4456-A2EE-A5092F5099F4, OS:15.5, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (5th generation) }
❌ [stderr] { platform:iOS Simulator, id:D38333AD-1820-41A9-9179-7BA12C6A00F9, OS:15.5, name:iPad mini (6th generation) }
❌ [stderr] { platform:iOS Simulator, id:B575F055-31BB-4681-A541-93C73D3E05F7, OS:15.5, name:iPhone 8 }
❌ [stderr] { platform:iOS Simulator, id:E65EE165-322D-430E-8955-428C34DC9E07, OS:15.5, name:iPhone 8 Plus }
❌ [stderr] { platform:iOS Simulator, id:EAFFB577-ED7C-4B60-A91D-20CF70EBFBA0, OS:15.5, name:iPhone 11 }
❌ [stderr] { platform:iOS Simulator, id:F6667EA1-F6F7-4304-B9D2-495992F0BC20, OS:15.5, name:iPhone 11 Pro }
❌ [stderr] { platform:iOS Simulator, id:F0CA4CF6-38BA-4D2E-AFBC-22EE1526754A, OS:15.5, name:iPhone 11 Pro Max }
❌ [stderr] { platform:iOS Simulator, id:4A1C0E71-0C96-40AD-A725-C6A370AF1D93, OS:15.5, name:iPhone 12 }
❌ [stderr] { platform:iOS Simulator, id:A5DACA53-368C-4AA9-B649-B1D379696C68, OS:15.5, name:iPhone 12 Pro }
❌ [stderr] { platform:iOS Simulator, id:1C40B471-BD95-4AD2-8E02-A4487E25EF3B, OS:15.5, name:iPhone 12 Pro Max }
❌ [stderr] { platform:iOS Simulator, id:4814B63C-8DE9-44CC-A80D-8D60D42C655A, OS:15.5, name:iPhone 12 mini }
❌ [stderr] { platform:iOS Simulator, id:8E2EB5DD-C321-4695-B728-F6A27FAF7D67, OS:15.5, name:iPhone 13 }
❌ [stderr] { platform:iOS Simulator, id:4E56612B-11ED-49F2-B5EF-6E4602B0FB79, OS:15.5, name:iPhone 13 Pro }
❌ [stderr] { platform:iOS Simulator, id:E5FAE80A-C4BD-4BFE-A831-2F7049886894, OS:15.5, name:iPhone 13 Pro Max }
❌ [stderr] { platform:iOS Simulator, id:E4D323B3-630D-4D28-A329-6870D721E3B2, OS:15.5, name:iPhone 13 mini }
❌ [stderr] { platform:iOS Simulator, id:DB03CB85-009E-4017-8EBE-14EC01AE8FD2, OS:15.5, name:iPhone SE (3rd generation) }
❌ [stderr] { platform:iOS Simulator, id:A147CC3C-E896-4D76-9012-878356117872, OS:15.5, name:iPod touch (7th generation) }
Detected provisioning profile mapping: {:"io.appnameapp"=>"ff123525-d8d9-4029-a284-ab263bce69ba"}

...


❌  error: File /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-gedwzmdsdqqlasgwhpmtmickdfvo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/appname/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/appname.app/main.jsbundle does not exist. This must be a bug with
```

Answer (score 1):

Scroll to the bottom of the build page. There should be an Xcode Logs section which you may not have noticed (as I didn't.)

If you examine those logs, you should be able to find the underlying JavaScript that's causing this issue.

For us, it was excluding a Babel plugin (which previously was not required somehow.) Adding it to our `.babelrc.js` fixed it.

Despite the error message saying it *must* be a bug with React Native - it's probably not.

Comment: Considering how big this log file is... did you just go to the bottom and start the search? Ive been looking around but nothing is catching my eye. I uploaded it to this questions. If you took a look, I would appreciate it more than you know.

Comment: Unfortunately nothing stands out to me as a cause. Since you got the app to build but not run, I think your next step would be to try to find a way to access the device logs - or probably easier, try running in development with the flags `--no-dev --minify` to make the DEV code run more like your PROD code. If all else fails, you might be able to find some help on the Expo Discord server.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! Ill reward you the answer in a couple days if nothing comes up :)